# Singularity does not "import" OpenGL / EGL libaries

Tags: opengl, nvidia, headless, egl, singularity-container

I have a Singularity container with plain simple Ubuntu installed:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04
#From: ubuntu --> I have tried both

%post
    apt-get update
```

When I go "into" the container

```
singularity exec --nv image.simg bash
```

I get no results for:

```
find /usr -type f -name "libGL*"
```

On my host system however I get:

```
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/common/lib/linux/aarch64/libGLEW.a
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/common/lib/linux/x86_64/libGLEW.a
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/common/lib/linux/armv7l/libGLEW.a
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.384.111
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGL.so.384.111
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLX_nvidia.so.384.111
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.384.111
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGL.la
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGLX.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.13.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1.3.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLESv1_CM.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.384.111
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGL.so.384.111
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLX_nvidia.so.384.111
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLESv2_nvidia.so.384.111
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGLX.so.0
```

I am using the `--nv` option which basically should be using the NVIDIA graphics from my host system and therefore this should be the same?

*NOTE*

```
find  -type f | wc -l
```

HOST: 4026
GUEST: 1602

Answer (score 0):

is a fail in nvidia-container-cli list
for fix remove *libnvidia-container-tools*